# Integração da Cielo com C# e Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando integrar a Cielo para realizar pagamentos no meu site "Asp.Net MVC" mas não estou conseguindo. Li o manual de integração da Cielo, segui todos os passos, realizei testes no Postman e funciona bem, mas na minha aplicação não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, sempre me retorna o erro: **Method Not Allowed** e olhando no site da Cielo, não encontrei uma forma de resolver esse problema.

Para integração, testei usando o HttpClient e o RestSharp e ambos retornam o mesmo erro.

Como resolver esse problema ?

```
//pagamento com cartão
public static bool Pay(CieloObject obj){

        try{
            string URL_FINAL = "https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br";
            string mid = "<meu-id>";
            string key = "<minha-chave>";

            var request = new RestRequest();
            request.Method = Method.POST;
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("MerchantId", mid);
            request.AddHeader("MerchantKey", key);
            request.Parameters.Clear();
            request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), ParameterType.RequestBody);             

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var client = new RestClient(URL_FINAL);
            var response = client.Execute(request);

            Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);


            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){

            return false;
        }       

       
    }
```

Comment: Posso estar falando besteira, mas você não precisa passar alguma coisa depois do "https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/METODO"? Ele não tem uma barra após isso?

Comment: @LeonardoButa nao tem. Veja: https://developercielo.github.io/manual/cielo-ecommerce

Comment: Segundo o site da [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) essa resposta significa que o método utilizado (POST) não é permitido, verifique se a url está correta e se o método é POST mesmo... Alguns servidores são case sensitive para cabeçalhos, tente usar o cabeçalho "Content-Type" (com as iniciais maiúsculas).

Comment: @Edney é POST sim. Inclusive no Postman funciona com POST

Comment: Eu não sou muito familiar com essa API, a CIelo não tem um suporte técnico que atende?

Comment: @Edney mandei email e não respondem

Comment: Dei uma olhada no seu link e me parece que as requisições são feitas no endereço: https://apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/1/sales/

Comment: não esqueça do "https://"

Comment: @Edney funcionou. O problema era o WebDav. Achei a solução aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854602/asp-net-web-api-405-http-verb-used-to-access-this-page-is-not-allowed-how